# Laravel rest API how do I get User thirdparty token in another endpoints

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-socialite

I am currently adding Spotify Authentification to just getting the Spotify Token to have acces to different features (User Features) and for example adding to a user connected some tracks to there playlist.

Also I made the Authentification system and when I receive the User Info in my callback endpoint, Laravel (Socialite) store him in a Session file, also I can't get it from different controller like to return all genres from spotify or other things ..

My api routes (Works perfectly)

```
Route::prefix('/spotify')->group(function () {
    Route::get('auth/redirect', function () {
        return Socialite::driver('spotify')
            ->setScopes(SpotifyController::READ_ACCES)
            ->redirect();
    });

    Route::get('auth/callback', function () {
        return response()->json(['message' => "Utilisateur connecté à spotify"]);
    });
});
```

When I try to print user() directly into the callback, it works perfectly.

Therefore when I want to get the user token from session (registered by Laravel Socialite) in another api endpoints (For example /api/genres)

```
Route::prefix('genres')->group(function() {
    Route::get('', [GenreController::class, 'index'])->name('genres.index');
});
```

```
class GenreController extends Controller
{
    protected function index(Request $request)
    {
        dd(Socialite::driver('spotify')->user());
    }
}
```

It return Invalid Exception state .. No session found ..

[image: invalid exception state]

Any idea on how to correct this ? Does I need to store the Spotify User access token into database for each of my Connected User directly ?

My session was correctly configured

```
        'web' => [
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
            'throttle:60,1',
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class.':api',
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
```

I want to have acces to the Spotify User access token from different API endpoints, obviously I cannot get him from Session file

Thanks for your help

Comment: Yes, you need to store the access token somewhere - session, database, etc. - for reuse. You can't call `Socialite::driver('spotify')->user()` again.

Comment: @ceejayoz I can store directly using session ? I only use laravel as an api, I will communicate with it from a Flutter mobile App ?

Comment: That depends on your use case. Sessions go away. You might store the token in your Flutter app, or in the API's database.